# Are Sword Art Online and Accel World related?

Tags: sword-art-online, accel-world

Recently, I have been hearing loads of theories about Sword Art Online and Accel World being related due to the fact that they refer to NerveGear and such in Accel World.

I have also been hearing that the plot of Accel World was made by Kirito.

Is there some sort of confirmation of this? Or trustworthy speculation?

Comment: Spoiler! In a side-story, Kirito also appears in Accel World.

Comment: @looper which side story ^^ provide me with links :D

Comment: It's the [Versus](http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Versus)-Crossover in Vol. 10 C. 3 of the Accel World Light-Novel.

Comment: YES because in the manga for sao he dives into the future and figts silver crow. plus, kawahara is the same autor in the manga.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are in the same universe.  Sword Art Online's Nerve Gear was elaborated in Accel World as a precursor to the implants seen in Accel World.

Anything further than that is likely speculation, until either light novel reveals more details.

Comment: ugh then guess ill have to wait to find out more :)!

Answer (score 15):

The author, Kawahara Reki, didn't clearly say whether they are in the same timeline or not. During the Sakuracon Festival Interviews, he answered like this:

> **When you were creating the [Alicization](http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Project_Alicization) arc in *Sword Art Online*, was the technology used in the Alicization arc carried over as a foundation to *Accel World*?**
>
> It is true that the technology used in Alicization could be, or is the foundation of the technology being used in *Accel World*, but at this point, like I said, it might be similar technologies having a similar technological chain, but it hasn't been made clear that it is in fact the same world. The two worlds could just have a similar technological advance. Also, as I noted before, if I were to clearly state the two worlds are the same, the number of things that need to be resolved in order for such a thing to be clearly possible is, the numbers are tens of thousands of times greater than I can even hope to do right now! Seeing a movie like [*The Avengers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Avengers_(2012_film)), where it took a bunch of properties into one cohesive title, I have to say that the creative staff on that movie is quite amazing.

Original link is ["Interview with Kawahara Reki" on Sutoraiku Anime](http://www.sutoraikuanime.com/2013/04/interview-with-kawahara-reki.html).

Comment: Really amazing interview. Good thing there is more information available ;). This is still no definite answer, but the way he speaks of it he actually is planning on linking it (thats how I feel he said it ) Thanks allot for adding the info

Answer (score 1):

Another point to add to this that I have yet to see is that when Haruyuki was looking up the older generation tech, they show a picture. At first glance, I saw the similarities, and it was when he actually said "Nerve Gear" (in [Episode 22](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpQRY.jpg)) that I freaked.

I'm not saying that it's definite that it's connected, but really, it's totally possible. At the end of the first season of SAO, he was given the seed that would enable other people to create their own worlds and games that others could come into. If the worlds aren't connected, then I'd be very disappointed, but at least it would make great fan fiction.

Answer (score 0):

Sword Art Online and Accel World exist within the same universe but at different times. Similar to Batman Beyond being in the future of Justice League and Batman the Animated Series. The technology in SAO is the first gen version of the tech in Accel World.

Answer (score -1):

SAO and AW are related because they have the same author and also in the one chapter of SAO and AW (versus) they meet and duel. (fact)

You may also think that the timeline also looks like this: SAO may be the first generation (nerve gear) until technology improves until the period of AW (neuro linker) is created. 
(opinion)

The timeline of past and future met and they have a duel because of that machine Kirito used and Silver Crow using that accceleration program. (opinion)

Comment: "are related because they have the same author" - this isn't necessarily true. While some authors might have some links between the different works they do, this isn't always the case (e.g. Hiromu Arakawa's Silver Spoon and Fullmetal Alchemist).