# Is there a Sword Art Online/Accel World crossover?

Tags: sword-art-online, accel-world, crossovers

Are there any crossovers of SAO and Accel World? Anime, manga, light-novel, anything?

I saw this image a long time ago somewhere:

[image: Black Swordsman, Silver Crow, and Cartman]

And I read about a possible crossover between the two. Does anyone know if it has aired yet or will be? And where I can find the episodes/chapters or find more information?

Comment: Related: http://anime.stackexchange.com/q/2470/

Comment: There is also a reference to nerve gear in the first season of the Accel World anime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's also [a crossover drama CD](http://vgmdb.net/album/52510). The second disc adapts the "Versus" storyline mentioned in [Astral Sea's answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/28995/); the first disc is just two separate storylines (one for AW, one for SAO) with no crossing-over.

Answer (score 6):

There is a crossover, but it is still just a Special Chapter called [Versus](http://swordartonline.wikia.com/wiki/Versus). It is just a fight between Kirito and Silver Crow, caused by a special dive machine. You can read a english version [here](https://www.baka-tsuki.org/project/index.php?title=Sword_Art_Online:Versus).

> Kazuto (Kirito) was on a part-time job to test out the 4th generation FullDive machine created by Rath. He was told that other users had seen a ghost and so he was there to check if it was true. During the dive he saw a robotic figure. He instinctively grabbed the sword hung on his back, only to discover that he was his avatar from Sword Art Online, Kirito the Black Swordsman. He looked up and saw a timer, health bar, stamina gauge on both sides of his vision, his login ID "KIRITO" on the left side and his opponent's ID, SILVER CROW, on the right.