# What is the chronological order of the Sword Art Online (anime) franchise?

Tags: sword-art-online, accel-world, gun-gale-online

*Sword Art Online* anime franchise includes movies and/or specials, like:

- *Sword Art Online II*
- *Sword Art Online: Alicization*
- *Sword Art Online Alternative Gun Gale Online*
- *Accel World*, etc.

I like to watch things in chronological order whenever I can help it.

What is the chronological order for the whole franchise?

Comment: Related: [Which anime story came first, Accel World or Sword Art Online?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/49795/1458)

Comment: I realize how similar the questions are, but mine is going a little bit more in-depth by asking for a complete timeline.

Answer (score 5):

In Accel World S1E22 ~17:00, the main character is doing some research which references the NerveGear.

(English Dub)

> NerveGear :  The first VR Machine of the 2020's

Therefore, the story timeline place Accel World after SAO.

Combined with various Wikipedia articles,  chronological order of the Anime is:

1. Sword Art Online
2. Sword Art Online Extra Edition (movie)
3. Sword Art Online 2
4. Sword Art Online : Ordinal Scale (movie)
5. Alternative Gun Gale Online (side story series)
6. Accel World
7. Sword Art Online : Alicization
8. Sword Art Online:  Alicization - War of Underworld
9. Sword Art Online:  Alicization - War of Underworld Part 2

A source of info is on [Fandom](https://swordartonline.fandom.com/wiki/Sword_Art_Online_Timeline).

Comment: I should add that the timeline link posted only mentions Accel World Volume 10 - "Versus" which is a crossover between SAO and Accel World. i assume this is what you mean for point 6 as i can't find anything else relating to Accel World (infact it takes place before Ordinal Scale according to the wiki). otherwise if you're suggesting Accel World started and took place before Alicization can you cite the evidence for this (site or mentions in the series)

Answer (score 0):

It is not just a strait line, but a graph
[image]

Source: [SAO Franchise](https://shikimori.one/animes/z11757-sword-art-online/franchise)

Comment: This does not appear to answer the OP's question. There are no titles, so it is very difficult to read, and the year that is shown is the release year, not the year the anime/movie took place

Comment: You may use source link. Every picture is clickable there.

Comment: First off, welcome to Anime & Mange! Relying on external links for the full details is generally frowned upon in SE. Even though you did link the source, the site is in Russian(?), making difficult for non-Russian speakers to rely on Google's (more-or-less) accurate translator. Finally, if the link were to ever go down, that information would be lost

Comment: ok). That site has also english version. And the main idea of my post was to show, that there is no exact chronological order. By chronological I mean causal relationship, when something what happened yesterday effects today situation.

Comment: Could you link the English version by chance? I did a bit of digging around your source with Google Translate on and I couldn't find the language setting. Also while its been a while since I followed SAO its story is largely causal isn't it? Especially the anime which goes SAO1, SAO2, (movie), SAO Alicization, Accel World. The GGO spin-off doesn't seem meaningfully tied into the main plot but it would be somewhere after GGO in SAO2 and I dunno what the other series on that chart are but they seem like supplemental things